# Tkinter no carga imagen

Tags: python, tkinter, pillow

Quiero colocar una imagen dentro de una ventana que creo mediante un objeto, la clase de dicho objeto tiene un método para agregar una imagen enviando la ruta absoluta como parámetro, aparentemente no da error, pero no aparece imagen alguna en la ventana.

Este es el `main`:

```
from tkinter import *
import os.path
from TkinterClassMetodos import graficos

ruta_ico = os.path.abspath("./Graficos/Udemy_Tkinter/img/IcoPython.ico")
ruta_img = os.path.abspath("./Graficos/Udemy_Tkinter/img/Posada.jpg")
ventana = graficos("Ventana",ruta_ico,"500x500", False)

ventana.cargar()
ventana.addImg(ruta_img)
ventana.mostrar()
```

Este es el método `addImg`:

```
def addImg(self, ruta):
        imagen = Image.open(ruta)
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)
        img = Label(self.ventana, image=render)
        img.pack()
```

Esta es la ruta absoluta al archivo que creé (copiada del explorador):

```
C:\Users\Ariana\Documents\Programacion-Web-BD\ProgramasPY\Graficos\Udemy_Tkinter\img\Posada.jpg
```

La carpeta abierta en Visual Studio Code es ProgramasPY

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guarda una referencia al `PhotoImage` que estás creando, de otra forma, la imagen no se muestra, no sé explicar la razón de por qué esto pasa, pero si que lo resuelve.

Ya que trabajas con una clase, puedes guardar la referencia en la propia clase, algo como:

```
def addImg(self, ruta):
        imagen = Image.open(ruta)
        self.render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)
        img = Label(self.ventana, image=self.render)
        img.pack()
```

Si utilizas el método para agregar varias imágenes, puedes guardar las referencias a cada una en un arreglo, por ejemplo:

```
def addImg(self, ruta):
        imagen = Image.open(ruta)
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)
        self.imagenes.append(render)
        img = Label(self.ventana, image=render)
        img.pack()
```

O incluso devolver la referencia y encargarte de almacenarla en el punto de llamada:

```
def addImg(self, ruta):
        imagen = Image.open(ruta)
        render = ImageTk.PhotoImage(imagen)
        self.imagenes.append(render)
        img = Label(self.ventana, image=render)
        img.pack()
        return(render)
```

Y entonces:

```
ventana.cargar()
refImagen = ventana.addImg(ruta_img)
ventana.mostrar()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Ya habia encontrado esa solucion, lo q todavia no entiendo realmente, es porque en el tutorial q vi, el chico q lo hizo hacia exactamente lo que yo y a él le funcionaba ._. mientras q a mi me tocó hacer malabares para simplemente poner una imagen.

Comment: Como te dije, desconozco el por qué de esta situación, no he tenido el tiempo para profundizar en ella (y quizás no lo haga), lo cierto es que con el _workaround_ que te digo aquí, funciona. Un saludo.