# imágenes en tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

estoy creando un programa en tkinter con Python que tiene la única función de que cuando oprima un botón aparezca una imagen   que| identifique pero al momento de oprimir el botón se  ejecuta pero no aparece la imagen

la imagen es llamada de la funcion cada vez que se oprima el boton dará el valor de 1 y si x es igual a 1 deberia imprimir la imagen de una manzana

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk as itk

raiz=Tk()


def imagen(x):
    if x == 1:

    img = itk.PhotoImage(file="manzana.jpg")
    lbl_imagen = Label(raiz, image=img)
    lbl_imagen.grid(column=2, row=2)

manzana=Button(raiz,text="manzana",command=lambda:imagen(1))
manzana.grid(column= 1 , row=2)



raiz.mainloop()
```

[image: ya ejecute el botón pero no sucede nada solo deja un espacio en blanco]

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Tkinter no carga imagen](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/448913/tkinter-no-carga-imagen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido Juanse c:

## Explicación

No tengo 100% claro la causa, pero tiene que ver con que la variable donde está guardada la imagen (en tu caso img), al ser local, se borra al finalizar la ejecución de la función imagen.
Cuando dicha variable es borrada, la imagen no se muestra.

Más información sobre como funcionan las variables globales y locales aquí:
[https://www.codigopiton.com/variables-locales-y-globales-en-python/#:~:text=En%20Python%20las%20variables%20locales,pueden%20modificar%20en%20funciones%20anidadas](https://www.codigopiton.com/variables-locales-y-globales-en-python/#:%7E:text=En%20Python%20las%20variables%20locales,pueden%20modificar%20en%20funciones%20anidadas).

## Solución

Lo que hay que lograr es que la variable donde se guarda la imagen de tkinter (en tu caso sería img) siga existiendo. Para tu caso especifico podemos hacer que la variable img sea global. Para lograr esto podemos cargar la imagen luego de iniciar la ventana.

Es importante realizar esta acción por fuera de la función para que Python defina a la variable como global y NO como local.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk as itk

raiz=Tk()
img = itk.PhotoImage(file="manzana.jpg")

def imagen(x):
    if x == 1:
        lbl_imagen = Label(raiz, image=img)
        lbl_imagen.grid(column=2, row=2)

manzana=Button(raiz,text="manzana",command=lambda:imagen(1))
manzana.grid(column= 1 , row=2)
```

*Nota*: No pude probar el código por que no tengo la imagen, pero estoy muy seguro de que funcionará. Si no funciona, dejame un comentario para avisarme.

Comment: gracias , si era aun problema de variables